# In what comics do the Avengers and the Phoenix Force battle in?

Tags: marvel, episode-identification, avengers-vs-x-men, chronological-order, phoenix-force

I've been keeping up with the Avengers vs X-Men storyline but in a couple of the ones I've read, I've gotten part of the Avengers vs Phoenix Force fight but not all of it.  The parts I've found are also somewhat disjointed:

> Thor appearing on the moon in AvX & what seems to be the finale of the fight in The Avengers, before Koh-Varr "kidnaps" them to the Kree homeworld.

Can anyone give me a list of the issues this fight is detailed in, and what order to read them in to get it in chronological order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I had (and still have) is that the following comics were released in only a series-internal consistent order.  The comics occurring within Avengers #26 still have not been all released, and Avengers vs X-Men #4 was released prior to the majority of the other comics.

The timeline as best I can determine:

1. Part 1 of **Avengers #26** - They head into space.
2. **Secret Avengers #26** - First battle with Phoenix Force.  Land on Hala
   to recover.
3. **Secret Avengers #27** - Not directly related to the battle, but fits
   in here in the timeline.
4. **Secret Avengers #28** - TBD.  Not released yet.  Probably contains second battle
   with Phoenix Force.
5. Part 2 of **Avengers #26** - Aftermath of second battle with Phoenix
   Force.  Third battle with Phoenix Force.
6. **Avengers #27** - Escape from being flown into sun.  Leaving Hala to return to Earth.
7. **TBD** - Why does Thor crash as opposed to land?
8. **Avengers vs X-Men #4** - Thor crashes to the moon.
9. **Avengers vs X-Men #5** - Remainder of team is shown in lunar orbit,
   and then lands on the moon.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the scenes in space where the Avengers "space team" is waiting to intercept the Phoenix force.  The details around that mission and the battle in space are depicted in Secret Avengers #26.